# Set front end label for customer attribute - magento

Tags: magento

I have a customer attribute which I setup using this script (I've only pasted part of it, the part related to the attribute)

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'age', array(
    'label'             => 'Age',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => true
));
```

I would like to set the front end label of the attribute to "How old are you?" but keep the Admin label to "Age". How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I too was having trouble with this and never successfully was able to get the label to stick during initial creation of the attribute. Had to go with your answer below.

One suggestion however would be to use $setup->_prepareValues($data_array); to initialize your array for the third parameter of addAttribute(). This will return an array with all the valid option keys for setting up your attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I managed after looking into magento

```
$labels = array();
$labels[0] = 'Age';//default store label
$labels[1] = 'Label for store with id 1';
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'age');
$oAttribute->setData('store_labels', $labels);
$oAttribute->save();
```

This did the trick.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: To update a product attribute's, I had to use this  `Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code')->setData('frontend_label', array('New Frontend Label for Store 0', 'New Frontend Label for Store 1'))->save();`